# check if found specific record then find another record with the same group

Tags: sql-server

I have a table

Master table

```
PROBLEM_ID  PROBLEM            PGROUP
1           Other Hardware     Hardware
2           Error On hardware  Hardware
3           PM                 Hardware
4           Service            Maintenance
```

and a detail

```
TERM          PROBLEM            PROBLEM_ID
S1G166901     PM                    3
S1G166902     PM                    3
S1G166903     Service               4
S1G166902     Other on hardware     1
S1G166901     Service               4
S1G166901     Other Hardware        1
S1G166901     Error on Hardware     2
```

i need to query if `PROBLEM_ID` = '3' then find a `PROBLEM` that have `PGROUP` = 'Hardware'

like this

```
TERM          PROBLEM            PROBLEM_ID    PGROUP
S1G166901     PM                    3          Hardware
S1G166901     Other hardware        1          Hardware             
S1G166901     Error on hardware     2          Hardware
S1G166902     PM                    3          Hardware
S1G166902     Other Hardware        1          Hardware
```

i try to use Outer apply but it's return too much row

my specific result is if they're not contain `PROBLEM_ID` = '3' then will not show but if contain will show all problem with pgroup ='Hardware' by term

i try this

```
SELECT p.TERM, p.Problem_ID,p.problem, PGROUP
FROM Problem_log AS p 
CROSS APPLY ( 
            SELECT s.pgroup, s.problem_id 
            FROM problem AS s 
            WHERE   s.problem_id = p.problem_id AND PGROUP = 'Hardware'  )as s

            WHERE  exists (Select s.PGROUP,s.PROBLEM_ID 
            from PROBLEM_LOG 
            WHERE problem_log.PROBLEM_ID = '3'  GROUP BY term) 
            ORDER BY TERM
```

my sequence is 
- Select data from table problem_log for problem_ID = '3'

- if problem_ID = '3' then For each record check found other problem (Hardware only)

Comment: The master, detail and results tables seem inconsistent.  Can you check, please, and correct if needed.

Comment: i edited @MichaelGreen

Comment: Why are you querying for `problem_log.PROBLEM_ID = '41'` when you want `problem_log.PROBLEM = 'PM'`?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson sorry for that, it's remain the same things because id is identity, so now I change to the same as querying for `PROBLEM_ID = '41'

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT p.TERM, p.Problem_ID,p.problem, PGROUP
FROM Problem_log p
INNER JOIN problem AS s
ON s.problem_id = p.problem_id
WHERE s.PGROUP IN
(
    SELECT PGROUP
    FROM Problem_log
    INNER JOIN problem
    ON Problem_log.problem_id = problem.problem_id
    WHERE Problem_log.PROBLEM_ID = 3
)
```

Comment: i try your code it's work like my code it's still show a value that not contain 'PM', first check is record have a problem = 'PM' then check other problem with a pgroup  = 'Hardware'

Comment: @TouchyVivace This one works when using your sample data. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/786c22/3).

Comment: @MikaelEriksson thanks for prove me that, there's will my own way to solve and check my database fault :)